# where can i find vala binding for libgimp?

Tags: vala, gimp, gobject, gobject-introspection

Where can I find vala binding for libgimp?

Or, can someone point me to clear (complete) instructions to get it from gimp source code? The instructions at https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Bindings are really too light for me.

Comment: The answer is likely "Join the GIMP project and help to create what you want".

Comment: I'm afraid this won't happen. Too unfriendly community for me.

Comment: Hm... I'm part of this community. What instances made you think it is unfriendly?

Comment: This is not against you. From years, from time to time I post some questions on #Gimp and got no responses (that's ok as it's how irc works, but a bit strange given the numbers of users) or harsh comments (this is stupid (or so on) even when what I suggested finally got incorporated in gimp... just 5 years later).

Comment: Hm... I got access to the IRC logs of the years past, if you could tell me what nick you have used I could look this up. What exactly was it what got incorporated now, btw?

Comment: Sorry no special nickname. Mypaint brushes tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no Vala bindings for GIMP at this time.
GIMP has had it "cross-process", "cross-language" procedure calling for long before *gobject introspection* (GIR) was in place, and that is exposed as the *Procedural Database* (PDB), which can be browsed at GIMP's help menu.

However, these PDB calls have never been re-written to take advantage of GIR, and can not be accessed in this way.  There have been over the years several language bindings for GIMP using the PDB, all of it but for Python's and Script-fu had fallen unmaintained over the years. [GIMP-Perl](https://github.com/GNOME/gimp-perl) was long lived, and used to even be packaged in some Linux distributions. Other than that, there have been at least experimental bindings for [Java](http://jgimp.sourceforge.net/) and [Ruby](https://git.gnome.org//browse/gimp-ruby/).

On the other hand, all image and pixel manipulation being made in current GIMP (the 2.9 development branch, soon to become GIMP 2.10) is made through [GEGL](http://gegl.org/) (Generic Graphics Library). GEGL is a modern gobject library that can be used with gobject introspection bindings, and will work from Vala using the instructions on the page you linked in the question.

Comment: Vala bindings for the related GEGL library are available from distributions' development file packages. If not currently available (for example [Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=877555)) then the binding can be downloaded from https://github.com/nemequ/vala-girs/blob/master/vala/vapi/gegl-0.3.vapi

Comment: This was not (only) for pixel manipulation but more for adding more file formats (or rather more complete). I got a working version I wrote for gimp-sharp years ago. But as gimp-sharp looks going to be unmaintained too I think this was just a waste of time.